# Instruments > Automation - Script and Editor Log open simultaneously

Tags: instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

In the Instruments Automation tool, is it possible to have the Script and Editor Log panes open simultaneously (e.g. vertically split)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No :)
I recommend to edit script in an external editor and then run via console. That's easy:
`instruments -w "iPad Air" -t "Automation" ~/My.app -e UIASCRIPT my_script.js`

Answer (score -1):

To add on this, please make sure you export the script first if you created it within the trace document and then delete it form the trace document. If you do not do that, it will be overwritten when you reopen the trace document with instruments.

Comment: If you don't provide a solution, please add further considerations as comment

Comment: @abarisone, That was meant to be a comment.

Comment: Didn't mean to be offensive. The point is: if you have an answer provide it, but if you have further comments use the "Add comment" feature. Thanks.